# Create GUI to run sp-commands using c#

Tags: 2010, powershell

I have a requirement to create a GUI that talks with sharepoint management shell and gives the output then and there.

i tried the solution given here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

but this runs powershell commands and not spcommands.
if i give for example get-spsite instead of get-process in the above code it throws me an error like this

Error in script : The term 'Get-spsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

i am using sharepoint 2010, .net 4.5, powershell 3.0(this is just FYI)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: FYI SharePoint 2010 doesn't play nice with Powershell 3.0, you may need to specifically target 2.0 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2796733

Answer (score 2):

To work with SharePoint using PowerShell you need to add this at the beggining of your script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0
```

Then commands will be available to use.